# valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript every object has a valueOf() and toString() method.  I would have thought that the toString() method got invoked whenever a string conversion is called for, but apparently it is trumped by valueOf().

For example, the code

```
var x = {toString: function() {return "foo"; },
         valueOf: function() {return 42; }};
window.console.log ("x="+x);
window.console.log ("x="+x.toString());
```

will print

```
x=42
x=foo
```

This strikes me as backwards .. if x were a complex number, for example, I would want valueOf() to give me its magnitude, but whenever I wanted to convert to a string I would want something like "a+bi". And I wouldn't want to have to call toString() explicitly in contexts that implied a string.

Is this just the way it is?

Comment: Have you tried `window.console.log (x);` or `alert (x);` ?

Comment: They give "Object" and "foo" respectively.  Fun stuff.

Comment: Actually, alert(x); gives "foo", and window.console.log (x); gives "foo {}" in Firebug and the entire Object in the Chrome console.

Comment: In Firefox 33.0.2 `alert(x)` displays `foo` and `window.console.log(x)` displays `Object { toString: x.toString(), valueOf: x.valueOf() }`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The reason why ("x="+x) gives "x=value" and not "x=tostring" is the following. When evaluating "+", javascript first collects primitive values of the operands, and then decides if addition or concatenation should be applied, based on the type of each primitive.

So, this is how you think it works

```
a + b:
    pa = ToPrimitive(a)
    if(pa is string)
       return concat(pa, ToString(b))
    else
       return add(pa, ToNumber(b))
```

and this is what actually happens

```
a + b:
    pa = ToPrimitive(a)
    pb = ToPrimitive(b)*
    if(pa is string || pb is string)
       return concat(ToString(pa), ToString(pb))
    else
       return add(ToNumber(pa), ToNumber(pb))
```

That is, toString is applied to the result of valueOf, not to your original object.

For further reference, check out section 11.6.1 [The Addition operator ( + )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) in the ECMAScript Language Specification.

---

*When called in string context, ToPrimitive *does* invoke toString, but this is not the case here, because '+' doesn't enforce any type context.

Comment: Shouldn't the conditional in the "actually" block read "if(pa is string && pb is string)"?  I.e "&&" instead of "||" ?

Comment: The standard definitely says "or" (see the link).

Comment: Yes that's exactly right--precedence is given to strings over other types in concatenation. If *either* operand is a string, the entire thing will be concatenated as a string. Good answer.

Answer (score 85):

Here's a little more detail, before I get to the answer:

```
var x = {
    toString: function () { return "foo"; },
    valueOf: function () { return 42; }
};

alert(x); // foo
"x=" + x; // "x=42"
x + "=x"; // "42=x"
x + "1"; // 421
x + 1; // 43
["x=", x].join(""); // "x=foo"
```

The `toString` function is *not* "trumped" by `valueOf` in general.  The ECMAScript standard actually answers this question pretty well.  Every object has a `[[DefaultValue]]` property, which is computed on-demand.  When asking for this property, the interpreter also provides a "hint" for what sort of value it expects.  If the hint is `String`, then `toString` is used before `valueOf`.  But, if the hint is `Number`, then `valueOf` will be used first.  Note that if only one is present, or it returns a non-primitive, it will usually call the other as the second choice.

The `+` operator always provides the hint `Number`, even if the first operand is a string value.  Even though it asks `x` for its `Number` representation, since the first operand returns a string from `[[DefaultValue]]`, it does string concatenation.

If you want to guarantee that `toString` is called for string concatenation, use an array and the `.join("")` method.

*(ActionScript 3.0 slightly modifies the behavior of `+`, however. If either operand is a `String`, it will treat it as a string concatenation operator and use the hint `String` when it calls `[[DefaultValue]]`. So, in AS3, this example yields "foo, x=foo, foo=x, foo1, 43, x=foo".)*

Comment: Also note that if `valueOf` or `toString` return non-primitives, they are ignored.  If neither exists, or neither returns a primitive, then a `TypeError` is thrown.

Comment: Thanks bcherry, this is the calibre of answer I was hoping for.
But shouldn't x + "x="; yield "42x=" ?
And x + "1"; yield 421 ?
Also, do you have a URL for the relevant part of the the ECMAScript standard?

Comment: Oops, yeah.  A typo and a mistake from testing `"1" + 1`, respectively.  I've edited the original post.  Thanks :)  

Here is the ECMAScript 3 specification (pdf): http://www.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf  

You're looking for `8.6.2.6 [[DefaultValue]] (hint)`, which is on page 35.

Comment: Actually, '+' doesn't use hints (see $11.6.1) therefore ToPrimitive invokes `[[DefaultValue]](no-hint)`, which is equivalent to `[[DefaultValue]](number)`.

Comment: Oh, interesting, stereofrog.  I didn't see anything about hints and `+`, but assumed it was using `Number` based on the result.

I also noticed that the unary `+` uses the `Number` hint (or no hint at all), but then calls `ToNumber` on the result.  This means that if `valueOf` returned a string, using unary `+` on that would return `NaN`, not the string, which is what I had expected.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for the built-in Date class. `("" + new Date(0)) === new Date(0).toString()`. A Date object always seems to return its `toString()` value when it's added to something.

Comment: +1 & Thx! I found [your blog-post in which you elaborate on this answer](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript.html) and wanted to link/share it here. It was really helpful addition to this answer (including Dmitry A. Soshnikov's comment).

Comment: @bcherry , so many scenarios to remmeber. Why not better to make by intention clear by explicitly calling valueOf() or toString(). What's your take on this approach ?

Comment: > _"If you want to guarantee that toString is called"_. Otherways: 1. Explicitly call `toString()` method. e.g. `console.log('x: ' + x.toString()); // "x: foo"`. 2. Coerce value to `String`. e.g. `console.log('x: ' + String(x)); // "x: foo"`.

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR**

Type coercion, or implicit type conversion, enables weak typing and is used throughout JavaScript. Most operators (with the notable exception of the strict equality operators `===` and `!==`), and value checking operations (eg. `if(value)...`), will coerce values supplied to them, if the types of those values are not immediately compatible with the operation.

The precise mechanism used to coerce a value depends on the expression being evaluated. In the question, the [addition operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus) is being used.

The addition operator will first ensure both operands are primitives, which, in this case, involves calling the `valueOf` method. The `toString` method is not called in this instance because the overridden `valueOf` method on object `x` returns a primitive value.

Then, because one of the operands in the question is a string, *both* operands are converted to strings. This process uses the abstract, internal operation `ToString` (note: capitalized), and is distinct from the `toString` method on the object (or its prototype chain).

Finally, the resulting strings are concatenated.

**Details**

On the prototype of every constructor function object corresponding to every language type in JavaScript (ie. Number, BigInt, String, Boolean, Symbol, and Object), there are two methods: `valueOf` and `toString`.

The purpose of `valueOf` is to retrieve the primitive value associated with an object (if it has one). If an object does not have an underlying primitive value, then the object is simply returned.

If `valueOf` is invoked against a primitive, then the primitive is auto-boxed in the normal way, and the underlying primitive value returned. Note that for strings, the underlying primitive value (ie. the value returned by `valueOf`) is the string representation itself.

The following code shows that the `valueOf` method returns the underlying primitive value from a wrapper object, and it shows how unmodified object instances that do not correspond to primitives, have no primitive value to return, so they simply return themselves.

```js
console.log(typeof new Boolean(true)) // 'object'
console.log(typeof new Boolean(true).valueOf()) // 'boolean'
console.log(({}).valueOf()) // {} (no primitive value to return)
```

The purpose of `toString`, on the other hand, is return a string representation of an object.

For example:

```js
console.log({}.toString()) // '[object Object]'
console.log(new Number(1).toString()) // '1'
```

For most operations, JavaScript will silently attempt to convert one or more operand(s) to the required type. This behavior was chosen to make JavaScript easier to use. JavaScript [initially did not have exceptions](https://2ality.com/2019/10/type-coercion.html#what-is-type-coercion%3F), and this may have also played a role in this design decision. This kind of implicit type conversion is called type coercion, and it is the basis of JavaScript's loose (weak) type system. The complicated rules behind this behavior are intended to move the complexity of typecasting into the language itself, and out of your code.

During the coercive process, there are two modes of conversion that can occur:

1. Conversion of an object to a primitive (which might involve a type conversion itself), and
2. Direct conversion to a specific type instance, using a constructor function object of one of the primitive types (ie. `Number()`, `Boolean()`, `String()` etc.)

**Conversion To A Primitive**

When attempting to convert non-primitive types to primitives to be operated upon, the abstract operation [`ToPrimitive`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) is called with an optional "hint" of 'number', or 'string'. If the hint is omitted, the default hint is 'number' (unless the `@@toPrimitive` method has been overridden). If the hint is 'string', then `toString` is tried first, and `valueOf` second if `toString` did not return a primitive. Else, vice-versa. The hint depends on the operation requesting the conversion.

The addition operator supplies no hint, so `valueOf` is tried first. The subtraction operator supplies a hint of 'number', so `valueOf` is tried first. The only situations I can find in the spec in which the hint is 'string' are:

1. `Object#toString`
2. The abstract operation `ToPropertyKey`, which converts an argument into a value that may be used as a property key

**Direct Type Conversion**

Each operator has its own rules for completing their operation. The addition operator will first use `ToPrimitive` to ensure each operand is a primitive; then, if either operand is a string, it will then deliberately invoke the abstract operation `ToString` on each operand, to deliver the string concatenation behavior we expect with strings. If, after the `ToPrimitive` step, both operands are not strings, then arithmetic addition is performed.

Unlike addition, the subtraction operator does not have overloaded behavior, and so will invoke `toNumeric` on each operand having first converted them to primitives using `ToPrimitive`.

So:

```js
 1  +  1   //  2                 
'1' +  1   // '11'   Both already primitives, RHS converted to string, '1' + '1',   '11'
 1  + [2]  // '12'   [2].valueOf() returns an object, so `toString` fallback is used, 1 + String([2]), '1' + '2', 12
 1  + {}   // '1[object Object]'    {}.valueOf() is not a primitive, so toString fallback used, String(1) + String({}), '1' + '[object Object]', '1[object Object]'
 2  - {}   // NaN    {}.valueOf() is not a primitive, so toString fallback used => 2 - Number('[object Object]'), NaN
+'a'       // NaN    `ToPrimitive` passed 'number' hint), Number('a'), NaN
+''        // 0      `ToPrimitive` passed 'number' hint), Number(''), 0
+'-1'      // -1     `ToPrimitive` passed 'number' hint), Number('-1'), -1
+{}        // NaN    `ToPrimitive` passed 'number' hint', `valueOf` returns an object, so falls back to `toString`, Number('[Object object]'), NaN
 1 + 'a'   // '1a'    Both are primitives, one is a string, String(1) + 'a'
 1 + {}    // '1[object Object]'    One primitive, one object, `ToPrimitive` passed no hint, meaning conversion to string will occur, one of the operands is now a string, String(1) + String({}), `1[object Object]`
[] + []    // ''     Two objects, `ToPrimitive` passed no hint, String([]) + String([]), '' (empty string)
 1 - 'a'   // NaN    Both are primitives, one is a string, `ToPrimitive` passed 'number' hint, 1-Number('a'), 1-NaN, NaN
 1 - {}    // NaN    One primitive, one is an object, `ToPrimitive` passed 'number' hint, `valueOf` returns object, so falls back to `toString`, 1-Number([object Object]), 1-NaN, NaN
[] - []    // 0      Two objects, `ToPrimitive` passed 'number' hint => `valueOf` returns array instance, so falls back to `toString`, Number('')-Number(''), 0-0, 0
```

Note that the `Date` intrinsic object is unique, in that it is the only intrinsic to override the default `@@toPrimitive` method, in which the default hint is presumed to be 'string' (rather than 'number'). The reason for having this, is to have `Date` instances translate to readable strings by default, instead of their numeric value, for the convenience of the programmer. You can override `@@toPrimitive` in your own objects using `Symbol.toPrimitive`.

The following grid shows the coercion results for the abstract equality operator (`==`) ([source](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/)):

[image]

### Addendum

Note that JavaScript coercion rules are designed to maintain internal consistency of behavior, and are not designed to meet your intuition (although they *usually* do).

So there are counterintuitive edge cases. For example, the following looks counterintuitive and inconsistent, but it is an artefact of maintaining consistent internal behavior

```js
!![] // true because Boolean([]) => true, [[Negation]](true) => false => [[Negation]](false) => true
[] == false // true because [].valueOf() => [], which is not primitive, fallback to [].toString() => '', Boolean('') => false, false === false => true
```

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792994/why-can-i-do-math-with-date-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here in You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md).

Answer (score 1):

## Simple answer:

When an object is added to something (using the `+` operator), any available `valueOf` method is preferred over the `toString` method.

`valueOf` is preferred even during a string concatenation operation.

## Full answer, with links to the ECMAScript specification:

To evaluate `a + b`, the internal operation [ToPrimitive](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.1) is [invoked](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) on each, with no [hint](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.6.1).

If [either of the results of the ToPrimitive conversions are strings](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.6.1), the results of those conversions are concatenated. If they are both numbers, they are added (mathematically).

When ToPrimitive is called on an Object, it [invokes](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.1) the internal operation [DefaultValue](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) on the object, again with no hint.

When the internal operation [DefaultValue](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) is invoked on an Object with no hint provided, it always [defaults](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) to the hint "Number" ([unless](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) it's a Date object). This means it [prefers](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) to use any `valueOf` method first, and then falls back to using the `toString` method.