# What is the result of adding an Object and an Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion

I tried this code in the address bar:

`javascript: alert({} + [])`

The result is: [object Object].

`javascript: alert(typeof ({} + []))`

The result is: string.

Can somebody explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concatenation operator (+) concatenates two string values together. If you give it things that are not string values, then it calls the `.toString()` method on them first.

In response to the comment below, "Yes it does!"

```
Object.prototype.toString = function () { return "a"; };
Array.prototype.toString = function () { return "b"; };
var foo = {} + [];
alert(foo); // alerts 'ab'
```

Without the above modifications to the prototypes, if you have `alert({} + [])` then you are taking `{}.toString()` (which is `"[Object object]"`) and `[].toString()` (which is `""` as the array is empty), then concatenating them (which is still `"[Object object]"`). This is a string and `typeof` will tell you that it is a string.

Comment: I changed the question because it doesn't convert both to string and then add them. You seems to be correct anyway.

Comment: So by default:
Object.prototype.toString = function () { return "[object Object]"; };
Array.prototype.toString = function () { return ""; };
Thanks, answer accepted.

Comment: It is something more like: `Array.prototype.toString = function () { return this.join(','); };`

Comment: @Jacob — Please don't hijack one answer thread to ask questions about a different one — and I've already given you my speculation as to why someone might have downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like because the `+` operator is not defined to accept arguments as one `[]` and one `{}`, it basically converts both to strings (makes more sense than trying to cast them into numbers) and then applies `+` as the concatenation operator.

Edit:
In response to the changed question, I think they are still being converted into a string first. Here's a session in spidermonkey where I tried it out:

```
js> x=[]+{}
[object Object]
js> z=x[0]
[
js> x.length
15
js> x=[]+{}
[object Object]
js> x.length
15
js> x[0]
[
js> x[1]
o
js> for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {print(x[i]);}
[
o
b
j
e
c
t

O
b
j
e
c
t
]
js> typeof(x)
string
js> print(x)
[object Object]
```

What is happening is that the result of `{}+[]` is a string, but not en empty string. Rather it is the string "[object Object]".

Comment: I changed the question because it doesn't convert both to string and then add them.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complex.

You'll find a very good explanation how it works here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript

But it seems the way ben cherry described did changed (also what I regonized). If you will run his example:

```
function population(country, pop) {
    return {
        country: country,
        pop: pop,

        toString: function () {
            return "[Population " + 
                "\"" + country + "\" " +
                pop +
            "]";
        },

        valueOf: function () {
            return pop;
        }
    };
}

var america_pop = population("USA", 350e6);
var mexico_pop = population("Mexico", 200e6);
var canada_pop = population("Canada", 200e6);

alert(america_pop); // [Population "USA" 350000000

var north_america_pop = america_pop + mexico_pop + canada_pop;

alert(north_america_pop); // 750000000
```

This isn't true anymore, the alerts will be:
 350000000
 750000000

alert(obj) call valueOf() not toString() anymore, execpt if you use Array.join

```
alert([america_pop]); // [Population "USA" 350000000
```

There was already a thread about: [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript)

They clearify that, valueOf is always called when [hint] is a number and that's always the case, except if you join an Array. that's confusing, because if you call 'string' + 'string' this is definitely a string context, but JS will first take look at the number context, and call always the valueOf() method not toString() if it's a primitive value

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's a little but more complicated than how it is explained here.

The question's title is:

#### What is the result of adding an Object and an Array in JavaScript?

And it then the question asks about the `{}+[]` expression, which everyone here assumes that evaluates to `'[object Object]'` - **but does it always?**

Press **Shift+Control+J** right now and type `{}+[]` at the `>` prompt:

[image]

Maybe it's a browser bug? Let's try the same in Node:

[image]

Something interesting is going on here.

The plus ( `+` ) - which is actually called the **"addition operator"** and not the **"concatenation operator"** as someone wrote here - see [ECMA-262, 6th Edition, Section 12.7.3 - The Addition operator ( + )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus) - either performs **string concatenation** or **numeric addition**, which is very important to understand examples like this.

Someone once asked me a question like this:

If `alert({}+[])` shows `'[object Object]'` and `x = {}+[]` puts '[object Object]' into `x` then why writing `{}+[]` in the Console or Node REPL gives `0`?

[image]

The answer is that while using the plus operator on object and array coverts them to strings - the string `'[object Object]'` and an empty string, respectively - here we are in fact **not** adding and object to an array! The `{}` is interpreted as an empty block and evaluated to nothing, so the `+` is now evaluated as a [unary operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator) coercing the `[]` array to a number, which happens to be zero for an empty array - but it is not the number of elements, but rather 0 for an empty array, the first element converted to a number if it can be or NaN if it can't for one-element arrays, and NaN for any arrays with more than one element.

Some more interesting results, try all combinations of `{}` and `[]` with `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` operators:

```
$ node
> []+[]
''
> {}+{}
'[object Object][object Object]'
> []+{}
'[object Object]'
> {}+[]
0
> []-[]
0
> {}-{}
NaN
> []-{}
NaN
> {}-[]
-0
> []*[]
0
> {}*{}
NaN
> []*{}
NaN
> {}*[]
... ^C
> []/[]
NaN
> {}/{}
NaN
> []/{}
NaN
> {}/[]
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:137:25)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:392:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:546:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:823:14)
```

This is one of the best ways to learn all of the quirks of the languages inside out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `toString` method will be invoked. You can actually override the default behavior by writing a `toString` method that returns a number.

```
var obj1 = {
        toString: function () {
            return 1;
        }
    },
    obj2 = {
        toString: function () {
            return 2;
        }
};
alert(typeof (obj1 + obj2));
```