# valueOf not working when i do alert(obj)?

Tags: javascript, html

This gives "[object Object]":

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
var a={};
a.valueOf=function(){
    return "asd";
};
alert(a);
</script>
```

but this gives "asd":

```
<!doctype html>
<script>
var a={};
a.valueOf=function(){
    return "asd";
};
alert(""+a);
</script>
```

i can understand why i get "asd" in the second example. But in the first example, shoudn't i also get "asd" since i'm putting the object through the alert function (which basically ends up calling the value-of anyway) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the + operator, JavaScript uses valueOf, and otherwise when a String is expected from an object, JavaScript uses toString(). Internally, perhaps in the Object.prototype.valueOf, it is designed to be the same as toString(). So, if you define only toString(), but not valueOf(), JavaScript will use toString() for both '+' (because internally valueOf calls toString) and in contexts where a String is expected. However, if you define valueOf, then that will be used where there is a '+' (or a - or / or any other arithmatic operator). But it won't be used when it expects a String (as in case of alert). It will call toString().

Answer (score 2):

Override `toString()` to achieve result you need:

```
var a={};
a.toString=function(){
    return "asd";
};
alert(a);
```

And look at this [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2485632/377133)

Answer (score 0):

"a" is an object so alert in case one is showing object, by doing alert(""+a) you are forcing "a" to be treated as string

Comment: but isn't it true that when i force it to be a string it's not the valueOf that runs but the toString?

Answer (score 0):

""+a  returns a string type. use typeof()  to check this.

http://jsfiddle.net/zYs73/

```
<div id='t'></div>

 <script>
    var a={};
    a.valueOf=function(){
        return "asd";
    };
    alert(a);
    document.getElementById('t').innerHTML += "<br/>" + typeof(a);

    var b={};
    b.valueOf=function(){
        return "asd";
    };
    alert(""+b);
    document.getElementById('t').innerHTML += "<br/>" +  typeof(""+b);
</script>
```

Comment: i mean i know that, but why doesnt the object gets converted into a string when i put it through the alert function?

Answer (score 0):

by doing ""+ you are trying to alert a string and with + you are trying to cast any values in string and then added to empty string ""

Comment: i mean i know that, but why doesnt the object gets converted into a string when i put it through the alert function?

Comment: Alert expects string and this is the nature of the javascript that it doesn't convert the object to make it workable for the alert.