# How can I subclass Boolean to change string representation without negative side effects outside of my function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, subclass, subclassing, prototypal-inheritance

I need to a way to wrap a boolean value such that comparisons are not broken and the string result is different than 'false' or 'true' without altering the global boolean values

```
function TestIt(bool){
    if(wrapper(bool) == true)
        return "it was: " + wrapper(bool)
    if(wrapper(bool) == false)
        return "it was: " + wrapper(bool)
    return "no dice"
}
```

e.g.

```
var result;
result = TestIt(true);
// "it was: True"
result = TestIt(false);
// "it was: False"
```

The attempts I have written have not been able to achieve all of the conditions below at the same time:

```
var initial = true;
var result1;
var result2;
(function(){
    result1 = wrapper(true);
    result2 = wrapper(true);
})()
// result1 == result2
// result1 == true
// result1.toString() != initial.toString()
// initial.toString() == true.toString()
// initial.toString() == (new Boolean(true)).toString()
```

Can anyone help me please?

I need this (automatic) alternate string conversion so that I can duplicate a string created on a server environment using a different language and match it exactly.

~~~~~~

Edit

~~~~~~

I forgot to mention that the trouble I am running into is the Boolean "valueOf" method that is called instead of toString (apparently) for string concatenation.

~~~~~~

Edit #2

~~~~~~

This would also need to work for false.  I just left that out for brevity.  However, wrapper(false) == false gave me a headache.

~~~~~~

Edit Final

~~~~~~

It turns out (in the answers below), that you can't override the default behavior like I wanted if string concatenation is used.  I am going to work on using an array to solve my problem and then doing custom conversions when I join it back together.  It seems like Javascript requires an oddball approach to a conceptually simple problem.

Code Example for command line:

```
function boolish(a){a=new Boolean(a);a.toString=function(){return this.valueOf()?"True":"False"};return a};

boolish(false) == false
boolish(true) == true
boolish(false) + " or " + boolish(true)
[boolish(false) , " or " , boolish(true)].join("~~~~~~~~")
```

Comment: Are you saying you expect `wrapper(true)` to evaluate to boolean true when used in your `wrapper(true)==true` statement, but `wrapper(true)` should evaluate to a string "True" if used in a string concatenation? That's not going to work.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, that is what I want.  Wrapper can return a new object or something.  It doesn't really matter how it happens... if it happens =).  I just can't figure out how to do it.  Notice that was wrapper(true)==true and not wrapper(true)===true with 3 equal signs.

Comment: @RobG that would not work for string concatenation

Comment: Couldn't you use a straightforward function to take care of outputting appropriately formatted string representations?

Comment: @davidchambers Not easily by any means.  This is simple in other languages =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you think you need this to happen automatically via `toString()`. If you have a "plain" boolean you can (obviously) use it in any comparisons as normal, but if you want to get some non-standard text when concatenated just specify it at the time. For example, if you wanted "TRUE" and "FALSE" all in caps:

```
var myBool1 = false,
    myBool2 = true;

alert("The value of myBool1 is: " + (myBool1?"TRUE":"FALSE"));
```

Or you could write a little function:

```
function boolToString(val) {
   return val ? "True enough" : "That's a lie!";
}

alert("The value of myBool2 is: " + boolToString(myBool2));
```

**EDIT** According to the following SO question (and answers): [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript) your requirement can't be done. The string concatenation + operator will always end up using `valueOf` rather than `toString`. I agree that this is weird. The workaround is to concatenate the strings without using the + operator, but I gather you don't want to do that.

Comment: I know that. What I'm saying is why you can't just do what I did in my answer and get on with it? That is, I can't think of a practical example why you'd need anything more. What's the point of this "wrapper" in your question?

Comment: Type "translation" from python to javascript for a template system that is already written.  I can't write tests to verify output if the template contains a boolean right now.

Comment: The link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript in your edit describes my problem exactly.  I am frustrated/confused by the design decision here, but nonetheless your answer appears to be correct when you say: "can't be done".  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
function myBool(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
myBool.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'The value is ' + (this.value? 'true' : 'false');
}

var x = new myBool(true);

alert(x);  // 'The value is true'
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you say `alert("X:" + x);` because then JS tries to use `valueOf`` instead of `toString`. (This is weird, but seems to be what the language spec says to do.)

Comment: A suitable method can be assigned to *valueOf* also, say: `myBool.prototype.valueOf = myBool.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @RobG Then myBool would never be false because the string is either "True" or "False"

Comment: You can't get `valueOf` to return a string when used for concatenation but a boolean when used in any other context...