# Is it possible to control how my objects are displayed when someone passes them to console.log?

Tags: javascript, console

Say I write a `Widget` class.

```
function Widget() {}
```

Someone using my `Widget` class sends an instance to `console.log`.

```
console.log(new Widget()); // ▶ Widget
```

Is there any way for me to control how that object is displayed in the console? Notice how the following are displayed:

```
console.log(window.location) // ▶ Location
console.log(document) // ▶ #document
console.log(document.body) // ▶ <body class="ask-page">…</body>
```

What if I want to display more useful information when a `Widget` instance is sent to `console.log`? I guess I could replace `console.log` with my own implementation, but I'm looking for something more elegant. Does `console.log` search for a particular function that can control the output?

**Update:** Some have asked what I'm trying to achieve. Here is a quick example. I wrote a `UrlBuilder` class in JavaScript that uses `Object.defineProperty` to create property accessors. (This is a constraint I cannot get around.) The problem is that whenever someone sends a `UrlBuilder` instance to `console.log`, I'd like to output the URL. However, instead it displays `▶ UrlBuilder`. And even if you expand the disclosure triangle, you don't see anything useful there because the property accessors are listed inside the `__proto__` property. It looks like an empty, useless object, and it would be more useful to display the URL as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding tostring() in your object with the representation you want the log to show.   Not 100% sure if this will work, but this is how it's done in other languages.  Also take a look at this: [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript), which might shed some light.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @DWright. I thought `valueOf` might be the solution, but that doesn't same to have any affect in Chrome's console. =/

Comment: And `toString()` doesn't either. Maybe the right answer is to file a Webkit bug.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the console has no standard, if you use the console from Firefox or Chrome, you get other outputs, sometimes you can jumt directly to the element (DOM-tab in firebug).

Whats the point you want to archieve with it?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *more useful information*? You can click on the left arrow in the console, to get the property list of the object.

Also, console.log implementation differs in every console. The firebug `console` will not output object the same way the `chrome dev tools console` will.

If you want to add informations to be logged with your object, perhaps you can wrap it into another before doing a console.log, but it only make sense as a debugging purpose : `console.log(myObjectWrapperFn(new Widget()));`