# Implicit coercion for objects

Tags: javascript

I am having troubles with implicit coercion with the + operator in JavaScript. Namely the priority order of valueOf and toString.

`var obj = {};`

`obj.toString();` => "[object Object]"

`obj.valueOf();` => Object {}

`'Hello ' + obj;` => "Hello [object Object]"

So obj is implicitly coerced to a string using the toString() method over valueOf();

```
var obj2 = {
    toString: function() {
        return "[object MyObject]"; 
    },
    valueOf: function() { 
        return 17;
    }
};
```

`obj2.toString();` => "[object MyObject]"

`obj2.valueOf();` => 17

`'Hello ' + obj2;` => "Hello 17"

So when I override the toString and valueOf methods, the + operator will coerce with valueOf.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Interesting... BTW, if you take out valueOf from obj2, the + operator will again coerce to toString

Comment: valueOf always prevails over toString when using Object arguments with the + operator.
Turns out obj.valueOf().toString() === "[object Object]";
Which makes sense now.

Comment: I wonder how can one really exploit this feature of Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be found in a similar thread: [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript)

If the object can be transformed into a "primitive" JavaScript will try to treat it as a number. Otherwise string concatenation via the `toString` method is used. Without the `valueOf` method, JavaScript cannot tell how to convert the data, hence the object will be concatenated as a string.

If you're interested the precise specifications are available in the following pdf at around page 58: http://www.webreference.com/javascript/reference/ECMA-262/E262-3.pdf

Hope that helped :-)

Comment: The pdf is loooong. It's kind of a weird question anyway. I get it now, the idea is that given var num = Object.valueOf(); and var str = Object.toString(); We should always have num.toString() === str; Otherwise we get the mess of the obj2 example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it more simpler to understand consider the following two cases -

```
var p = {};

//Case 1, here valueOf() method is called.
console.log(p); //Prints: Object {}


//Case 2, toString() method will be called.
console.log('the value of p is'+ p); //Prints: the value of p is[object Object]
```

So basically it depends on the way you are using this object.

Comment: In case 2, valueOf() is called first, then toString() gets called.

Comment: valueOf is always called when ever you refer the 'p' variable, try this p === p.valueOf() //returns true