# Join() vs toString() vs valueOf() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me the exact difference between `join()` and `toString()` and `valueOf()`in Javascript. When and at what situation we need to use them?

Comment: > Join -> join all elements of an array into string > toString -> returns a string representation of an object > toString (on array) ->Returns a string representing the specified array and its elements. Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1784500.aspx/1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript & http://jsperf.com/tostring-join

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`toString` is a method that you can find not only in `Array`s, but in every object.

`join` allows you to convert every element of the `Array` object in to a string, and joining together using a separator. It behaves just like `toString` for `Array`s, but you can also specify the separator:

```
var classes = ["first", "second"];
classes.join(" ");    // "first second"
```

Comment: what about indexOf()?

Comment: @VinothBabu `valueOf` is another generic object method, and it's used to get a numeric value from the object. It has little to do with `toString` or `join`.