# How can an empty string plus an object equal a number

Tags: javascript, string, object, addition

```
v = {
toString: function () { return 'foo' },  
valueOf: function () { return 5 }
}
console.log('' + v); //5
console.log(v); // { [Number: 5] toString: [Function], valueOf: [Function] }
```

Why does the v object get the value of 5?

Comment: The answer seems obvious to me.  It appears to be using the value returned from `valueOf` when being concatenated with the string.

Comment: I do not get what you are asking. Which object gets the value of 5? just try the following in your browser's console:

`v = {
  valueOf: function () { return 5 },
  toString: function () { return 'foo' }
}
temp = '' + v;
Number.isInteger(temp);`

you will see that the last command will print out false; hence empty string plus an object does not seem to be equal to a number.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I was asking why the v object would get the value from valueOf rather than foo from toString or why it wouldn't try to add an empty string to an object and give back something like NaN or undefined?

Comment: First of all, you'd never get `undefined`, `null`, or `NaN` from concatenating something with an empty string.  You should always get a new string.  Now the reason the string concatenation invokes the `valueOf` method of `v` is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2485632/2727710.  So this might be a duplicate question actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating an object, `v`, and overriding its `valueOf()` method to return the integer 5. If an object does not have an explicit `valueOf()` method defined, then `valueOf()` returns the object itself. All built-in core objects in JavaScript override this method to return the appropriate value. For example, doing the following:

```
x = 5;
console.log(x)
```

is really doing:

```
console.log(x.valueOf()) // log the return value of x.valueOf()
```

You can read more about `valueOf()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

---

If you are asking about why the addition (+) operator returns an arithmetic addition (calling v.valueOf()) instead of concatenation, you need to refer to the ECAMScript specification for the answer. [Section 11.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) talks about the addition operator. Here is the relevant bit:

> 5. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 6. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
> 7. If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim).

It looks like the operands should be resolved into string types before number types, so your expression `''+v` should call `v.toString()` first, and thus return `foo`, right?

Actually, no. Because in step 5 and 6, both operands are resolved into their primitives first, and this resolution is done without "hint". When there is no hint passed to ToPrimitive, Objects return their default values, which is the return of the `valueOf()` method. See section [9.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) for how Objects resolve into their primitives.