# How does type coercion with "+string" work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, types

I came across this recently, "+string" converting the string to a number (specifically, using the plus operator in front of a string or string variable for type coercion), but wasn't able to find documentation or discussion that satisfied my interested. I get the impression it's lazy or could have unintended side effects, but I want to understand it better. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example, of how it is being used?

Comment: Not for concatenation, but for type coercion.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

Comment: Again, not asking about the arithmetic operator. Asking about type coercion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html) describes in [section 12.5.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-UnaryExpression):

> **12.5.6 Unary + Operator**
>
> *NOTE*       *The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.*

So in JavaScript, the unary `+` operator (e.g., `+x`) will always convert the expression `x` into a number. In other words, the following statements are equivalent:

```
var x = Number('1234');
var y = +'1234';
```

This also works on *any*  variable, not only strings or numbers. If the object you try to convert is not an string or number, then the `toString()` method of that object will be called to convert the object into a string, and then that will be converted into a number. For example:

```
var obj = {
  toString: function() { return '9999'; }
};
var num = +obj; // = 9999
```

Comment: Right, I'm interested to know how that works under the hood.

Comment: Well, I'd say that's prety much how it works under the hood, it just calls the `Number` constructor (or at least its internal equivalent) and converts the argument to a number.

Comment: Looks like `+`, calls `valueOf()` method, if it's available, otherwise calls `toString()` method, and then converts the returned value to Number. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485794/1812434) answer.

Answer (score 2):

The unary plus operator is the same as unary minus. You are probably familiar with this syntax:

```
const a = 1;
console.log(-a); // -> -1
```

What happens is the value of `a` is type-casted to Number, and then the operation is applied to resulting value. This is why you will end up with `NaN` if you try to apply unary operator to a string, say

```
const a = 'abc';
console.log(-a); // -> NaN
```

although the string `"123"` will be successfully type-casted to a Number `123`, and you'll see `-123`:

```
const a = '123';
console.log(-a); // -> -123
```

The `+` works the same way but it doesn't negate the value. So if you do

```
+123
```

the value will remain `123`. If you do

```
+'abc'
```

the value will be `NaN`, just as in case with `-'abc'`. But if you do

```
+'123'
```

then `"123"` (string) will be type-casted to `123` (number), applied with `+` (nothing happens to the number), and returned. So you'll end up with `123` (number).