# Explanation of a function that uses toString method and recursion to sum numbers

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS, and would like to understand this example I have come across:

```
function sum(a) {

  let currentSum = a;

  function f(b) {
    currentSum += b;
    return f;
  }

  f.toString = function() {
    return currentSum;
  };

  return f;
}

console.log( sum(1) ); // f 1
console.log( sum(1)(2) ); // f 3
console.log( sum(5)(-1)(2) ); // f 6
console.log( sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) ); // f 0
console.log( sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) ); // f 15
```

What I don't understand is how is this function returning antyhing with just the call `sum(1)`, when I thought since we return only the function with the first call?
Also, what exactly is this `toString` method doing here, and how is this giving the `f 1`, and so on results?
I really hope some can explain this, since I can't understand what is going in this code from the tutorial. Apologise if the question is to noob.

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger to go through the code line by line. Then you can see exactly what the code is doing every step of the way. There are many tutorials on how to do this. [Here's one for Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/#step_3_step_through_the_code).

Comment: `console.log` seems to be calling the function's `toString` method. Test: `function f() {}; f.toString = () => 'abc'; console.log(f);`. To learn more about `toString`, have a look at [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2485632/218196) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log the result of a function, it needs to convert that result to a string. Some browsers do this by calling its `.toString()` method.

`sum()` returns a function that adds its argument to the `currentSum` variable in the closure. That's how the chained function calls accumulate a total. But this function also has a custom `.toString()` method that returns the sum that was calculated, so this is what gets logged.

We can break down one of the long chains like this:

```
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3));
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp1 = sum(1); // sets currentSum to 1, returns f
temp2 = temp1(2); // sets currentSum to 3, returns f
temp3 = temp2(3); // sets currentSum to 6, returns f
console.log(temp3); // calls f.toString(), which returns currentSum, so 6 is printed
```

This is a cute trick, but it's not a useful general method for allowing chained calls like this. It depends on the fact that after all the calls are done, the final result will be used by something that requires a string. It's depending on a browser-specific feature of `console.log()` -- it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Note that firefox logs `function()` and doesn't use toString automatically so it seems to be environment dependent also

Comment: Thank you for this nice explanation, but one thing is still unclear to me, I thought that if we overwrite ```toString``` method, that it would be called each time we try to log something in the console, like ```sum(1)(2)``` for example. Which it does, but I thought that if that happens, that the ```function f(b)```  wouldn't be even called if the ```toString``` method is already called. How and why is the ```function f(b)``` called when the ```toString``` method executes? Would be very thankful if you could clear this up as well.

Comment: The arguments to a function are evaluated before calling the function. So `sum(1)(2)(3)(4)` is calculated before calling `console.log()`. The value returned by `f(4)` is passed to `console.log()`, it then calls `toString()`.

Comment: Then how are we getting the value first time if we don't have the b value yet, when I call only ```sum(1)```. Then the function ```f(b)``` should be called first as well, and resolved and it should get an error since we haven't passed ```b``` argument? What am I missing here?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a detailed explanation of one call

Comment: The first call to `sum(1)` does `let currentSum = a;` which sets it to `1`. We don't need to call `f(b)` the first time, because we're not adding anything more.

Comment: Ah, that is why ```f``` is also logged as well with the ```currentSum```, the function it self always returns ```f```, and ```toString``` always returns ```currentSum```, if I understood it correct.

Comment: Apparently `console.log()` first notices that it's a named function, so it prints the name of the function. Then it calls `toString()` to get what it expects to be the definition of the function.