# Is String function valueOf() is useless in JS String library?

Tags: javascript, html, string

What is the use of valueOf() string function when I can get result without it also?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<button>Click Me</button>

<script>
var a = "Good Morning!"; 
$('button').click(function(){
alert(a);
var x = a.valueOf();
alert(x);
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, very simply I can output the variable value by alerting it itself. Then, what is the use of valueOf() function in string library of JS. Is it useless?

Comment: Related: [valueOf() vs. toString() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2485632/11683)

Comment: strings also have a `toString` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) function gives you the underlying content of the String that you being used. As I quoted below, Javascript calls it internally and gives you the content of it from the String Object. So when it is String it doesn't make sense to call it. But for other objects it makes sense.

> JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value. You rarely need to invoke the valueOf method yourself; JavaScript automatically invokes it when encountering an object where a primitive value is expected.

And from [docs of String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/valueOf)

> The valueOf() method of String returns the primitive value of a String object as a string data type. This value is equivalent to String.prototype.toString().

**This method is usually called internally by JavaScript and not explicitly in code.**

Comment: Can you edit the example to demonstrate what are you saying!

Comment: Care a new fiddle depicting what you mean to say?

Comment: actually, a String object overrides the Object.prototype.valueOf method ... `String.prototype.valueOf !== Object.prototype.valueOf`

Comment: Correcting your opening statement that String `valueOf` is inherited from Object `valueOf`

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/valueOf

`var a = "Good Morning!";` is string literal notation.

But if you were to define this as `var a = new String('Good Morning!');`
The only way to get sensible output of the string would be to use `a.valueOf();` or `a.toString();`

Answer (score 1):

valueOf() is useful when you create a string by String constructor.

```
let a = new String('Abcd');
// a is String object
// a.valueOf() is 'Abcd'
```

Here a will have the whole String Object and to get the string you must call a.valueOf();

But if you write

```
let b = 'Abcd';
```

valueOf() has no use. Hope that answers your question.