# Add a return type of string when a function is accessed like a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am not sure if this is possible (in fact I'm struggling to work out what to google for) but here it goes:

I have a function

```
const test = () => {
  some logic..
  return bla
}
```

now when I use 'test()' I want the function executed. But when I use 'test' I want a custom string to be returned. Is it possible to achieve this via Object proxies somehow?

Comment: Where is the "custom string" coming from? And what do you mean by "when I use 'test'"? When you don't call the function?

Comment: what do you mean 'I use test, I want custom string?

Comment: I mean when in one place I write 'test()' I want the function executed. But in another place if I don't have the brackets (i.e. it is not treated like a function) - it instead should return a string (let's say that string is '123')

Comment: What do you mean `in another place if i dont have the brackets`? Do you mean `console.log(test)` should log a custom string? Just a tip; When writing a question, it makes it easier for us if you put some example code of what you are trying to do *and* some expected output.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, I am not sure if I could have made it any clearer? I want to define different behaviours for test when I call it like a function and when I access it like a variable (i.e. without brackets)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to achieve this via Object proxies somehow?

No, this is not possible. You cannot make a callable proxy as a primitive string. If you want your `test` (function) object to show a custom string *when stringified* (like when concatenated to an other string), just give it a [custom `.toString()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2485632/1048572):

```js
const test = Object.assign(() => "Hello World", {
  toString() {
    return "123";
  }
});
console.log("Example call " + test());
console.log("Example stringification " + test);
console.log("Function object", test);
console.log("as a string", String(test));
```

Comment: From your example link, where an object has a default toString implementation - so can that object also be called like so: obj() where that executes some code?

Comment: could you please give me an example with the test function I have provided how I could achieve '123' returned when I type 'test'

Comment: @DeanR: *"so can that object also be called like so: obj() where that executes some code?"* No. Only functions are callable.

Comment: @DeanR I added an example. Notice that logging `test` on its own does not give the correct output in a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you first check the type of the variable, in particular you will check if its a ***Function***:

```
function isFunc(functionToCheck) {
 return functionToCheck && {}.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
};
```

So if this is true, then your variable is infact a function and you can return the stuff you need from it:

```
const isItAFunction = somevariable;

if(isFunc(isItAFunction)) {
   // return your string
} else {
  // do something else
}
```